# Office 2013 and Exchange Server 2019 compatibility issues

Tags: outlook-2013, microsoft-office-2013, exchange-server

I am planing a migration from Exchange Server 2010 to Exchange Server 2019. My main problem are 300+ Windows 7 client machines running MS Office 2013. I am aware of the TLS 1.2 issue and I plan to solve it with updates

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392

There is another possible issue regarding Office 2013 compatibility with Exchange 2019. Outlook 2013 is listed as supported as long as it has the latest updates

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix?view=exchserver-2019#clients

Does anyone have experience regarding this issue? What updates for Office 2013 are actually required for Outlook to successfully connect to Exchange 2019?

Comment: The article seems clear on this point: **Requires the latest Office service pack and the latest public update** - So make sure your Outlook clients have the latest service pack and the latest public update. Are you trying to determine what is the lowest supported update level? If so, why? Just update them to whatever is the latest.